# How can I identify combination that provides the sweetest juice to me?

Tags: machine-learning

I have apple, orange, grape, berry juice. By mixing them, I'd like to find the best combination that provides the sweetest juice to me.

I can measure vitamin of each juice: vitamin-A, -B, -C, -D. I can also measure sugar content after mixing them. But, combination (ratio of the juice) is inifinte, so, I'd like to find it by using a Machine Lerning method. How should I do?

1. Take trainig data at first, e.g. 100 combination?
2. Trainig model (multi layer perceptron?), where inputs are apple-ratio, apple-vitamin-A, apple-vitamin-B, ...., orange-ratio, ...., and output is the sugar content.
3. Complement the parameter space (the ratio, here?) with inference (by inputting different apple-ratio, orange-ratio, ...) to find the optimal sugar content

Are there other nice methods?

Answer (score 2):

Does mixing different vitamins change the sugar content?

If not, then solution is trivial: measure the sugar content of each of the juice, and pick the highest one. Any other combinations will dilute the sugar concentration.

=============================**Edit**=============================

One common mistake in any domain is to focus on the tools instead of the problem.

1. Define the target clearly. By *"the sweetest juice to me"*, is it a subjective (you taste and tell; others may disagree) or an objective (e.g. can be defined by measurement of certain chemical(s)) goal?
2. Assume the goal is objective, is there a fruit which is **always** measured to be the sweetest? If yes, pick this fruit.
3. If not, do we know anything which casually affect the sweetness level? Can we measure them?
4. Otherwise, do we know anything which correlates with the target? Do **not** put measures in just because they are available. In your case, can you logically speculate that vitamins are related to sweetness? If not, drop them. I can easily measure my height, weigh and heartbeat, but they don't help predict my commute time.

These are the type of starting questions you should think about before all buzzwords e.g. machine learning, deep neural network, genetic algorithm and what not. Ask the right question, and you will see the right solution.

Comment: Its just assumption, the sugar content might change, in that case, measurement is necessary. Another assumption is that the measurement requires long time. in that case, the best way is ML, right?

Comment: Then how would the measurement of sugar content change? Depend on what?

Comment: ok, maybe, I should not use vitamin-A, ...,  alternatey, I use parameter-A ,... which are strongly relate to target variable.

Comment: again, take a step back - what is the advantage of measuring a number of parameter-XYZ over directly measuring the sugar concentration? In either case you have to do measurements.

Comment: another thing to think about is: why the mix? For example, say the sugar concentration of apple, orange, grape, berry juice are 100, 50, 20, and 10 mg/L respectively. Then the sweetest juice would be 100% apple juice. Mixing it with other juices would only give you a diluted (less sweet) juice.

Answer (score 0):

This is an optimization problem:

- The proportion/amount of each fruit are the parameters
- For any specific combination of parameters you can obtain the final sugar content (objective function)
- The goal is to find the combination which maximizes sugar content

There are different approaches for this. [Genetic algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genetic_algorithm) are usually a quite simple and efficient method for this.

Comment: optimization problem to look for a combnation that gives me desired a target variable

Comment: Not sure what you mean? A target variable is usually a value that one wants to *predict* based on some inputs. Here you don't want to *predict* the sweetness and you don't know the values of the components as input; instead you want to *maximize* the sweetness and return the corresponding values of the components -> this is optimization.